# lldb Rust debugger breaks in VSCode when using openssl crate

Tags: rust, lldb, heroku-postgres

I'm very new to rust so please be kind.

I need to connect to a Postgres database on Heroku, which requires SSL certification. I can see that I can get around this with:

```
    let mut builder = SslConnector::builder(SslMethod::tls())?;
    builder.set_verify(SslVerifyMode::NONE);
    let connector = MakeTlsConnector::new(builder.build());

    let client = Client::connect(
        &database_url,
        connector,
    )?;
```

The whole script works fine with `cargo run`. However, when I try to use the debugger, I get shown the disassembly code.

I've narrowed it down and if anything from the openssl crate is in scope, I get this problem. I'm using an M1 Macbook.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

This is my launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "lldb",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/target/debug/${workspaceRootFolderName}",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "cargo": {
        "args": ["test", "--no-run", "--lib"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```